# DynamoDB Query 'Key' object has no attribute 'NOT_NULL'

Tags: python, dynamodb

El objetivo de esa función es obtener el item que coincide con la Key1 y que la Key2 no sea null.

```
def obtener_data_url_qry(tabla, key1, dynamodb=None):
    #  Obtiene toda la data de una URL (parametro entrada)

    if not dynamodb:
        dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='%%%%%%')

    table = dynamodb.Table(tabla)
    response = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('key1').eq(key1) & Key('key2').not_null()
    )

    return response["Item"]
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> 'Key' object has no attribute 'NOT_NULL'

Entiendo el error, pero no entiendo cómo solucionarlo. En la documentación no encuentro un manual de cómo usar la comparación "not_null".

Ya intenté con las siguiente variaciones de not_nul:

```
& Key('key2').not_null()
& Key('key2').not_null
& Key('key2').NOT_NULL()
& Key('key2').NOT_NULL
```

Y todas devuelven el mismo error.

Comment: No se nada de dynamodb, pero no hay una forma de negar una condición?, En pandas sería ~ el que actuaría como negación. Es decir, no existe algo como ~Key('key2').null()? (si es que null existe)

Answer (score 0):

Segun la documentacion de "boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Key", no se incluye ningún método, "not_null()" en ninguna de sus variaciones de escritura. Los siguientes son sus métodos:

```
begins_with()
between()
eq()
gt()
gte()
lt()
lte()
```

Usa una "FilterExpression" en vez de una "KeyConditionExpression" para poder usar "boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Attr" y podrás sus métodos, aquí algunos:

```
contains()

exists()
#Creates a condition where the attribute exists.

ne()
#Creates a condition where the attribute is not equal to the value
```

Intenta usando .exists() o .ne(None)

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/dynamodb.html#ref-dynamodb-conditions

por ejemplo:

```
response = table.scan(FilterExpression=(
                        Attr('field1').contains(request_json[i]) or
                        Attr('field2').existis())
```

puedes revisar la documentacion del metodo "Query" de "Table"

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.query